# writing .mat data to file in Google Drive using google colab

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, google-colaboratory, mat

I'm using google colab and I want to save an array in a .mat file, I used this code

```
import scipy.io
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
mdic = {"x": x, "label": "array_data"}
scipy.io.savemat('x.mat', mdic)
```

here I could download this file on my computer, I want to know if there is any code that can save this file automatically to a folder in my google drive?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to connect to your Google Drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
import os
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After this you can access contents of your Google Drive at `/content/drive/MyDrive':

```
! ls /content/drive/MyDrive
```